# Cannot able to start apache2

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy

```
Oct 04 14:13:29 ip-172-31-0-218 apache2[20813]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Oct 04 14:13:29 ip-172-31-0-218 apache2[20813]: Output of config test was:
Oct 04 14:13:29 ip-172-31-0-218 apache2[20813]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 13 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
Oct 04 14:13:29 ip-172-31-0-218 apache2[20813]: Invalid command 'ProxyPass', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Oct 04 14:13:29 ip-172-31-0-218 apache2[20813]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Oct 04 14:13:29 ip-172-31-0-218 apache2[20813]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Oct 04 14:13:29 ip-172-31-0-218 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 04 14:13:29 ip-172-31-0-218 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
```

I just added the Proxypass and proxyreversepass in the sites-enabled file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running these commands:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy_ajp
a2enmod proxy_balancer
a2enmod proxy_connect
a2enmod proxy_html
```

Then try again to restart apache.